# Hibernate many to many query not equal

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

При таком запросе:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails,Serializable{
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="recipients")
   private List<Project>recipientsProjects = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="projects")
public class Project implements Serializable{
   @Id
   @Expose
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;
   @Expose
   private String name;
   @ManyToMany
   @Expose(serialize=false)
   @JoinTable(name = "project_recipient",schema="post",
   joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id",referencedColumnName =     
   "id")},
   inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName =   
   "id")})
   private List<User>recipients = new ArrayList<>();
}


mySql = "SELECT u FROM User u join ";
mySql+= "u.recipientsProjects r WHERE r.name NOT LIKE :project";
query = em.createQuery(mySql);
query.setParameter("project", project.getName());
List<User>users = query.getResultList();
```

все равно выводит юзера с таким проэктом. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно запрос сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: Какой-то странный у Вас запрос. В списке полей указан алиас таблицы. Джойнится не таблица, а поле этой таблицы. Не может такой запрос быть выполнен

Comment: @AntonShchyrov добавил описание поля в Entity

Comment: Судя по тексту запроса _SELECT u FROM User u join u.recipientsProjects r WHERE r.name NOT LIKE :project_. имеется база данных с именем u, в которой есть таблица recipientsProjects, в которой есть поле name, и текущая база данных (возможно, та же), в которой есть таблица User, в которой есть поле u. Это - правильно?

Comment: @Akina есть фирма(проект) в фирме работают люди(юзеры) у фирмы есть название(имя). Связь ManyToMany у юзера List<Project>recipientsProjects, а у проекта List<User>recipients. Нужно выбрать всех исполнителей, несостоящих в проекте с именем ":project".

Comment: Лучше добавьте в вопрос DDL всех таблиц. И там же в вопросе опишите все вот эти связи, если они не организованы с использованием FK.

Comment: @Akina добавил таблицу

Comment: _добавил таблицу_ НЕ ВИЖУ! DDL таблицы начинается с `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: А, я не понял....Это hibernate(ORM) вручную я таблицы не пишу

Comment: Ааа... ну тогда я пас. Ждите того, кто может понять, что будет создано Вашим кодом...

Comment: Попробуйте `mySql+= "u.recipientsProjects r WHERE str(r.name) NOT LIKE :project";`

Comment: @Komdosh Пробовал....Тоже самое....Проблема, насколько я понял, в следующем: пока у юзера 1 проект все работает нормально, если у него больше одного проекта, то, похоже, движок проходит по дополнительной таблице и как только натыкается на первую запись с другим проектом тут же выбирает юзера как без проекта указаного в запросе.